# Ticket processing system

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Is paypal a suitable system for handling event ticket payments. All I want to do is create a page with event details, a list of hOw many tickets are left and a secure payment handling. Systems like eventwax seem to charge for use of there system and then paypal charges you too. I just dont get why people are paying twice. Also does anyone have any other recommendations for similar sites like eventwax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Checkout lets you do something that will work for you. Basically you create a Google Docs spreadsheet that follows a special format and contains the items that you sell and the quantities remaining. Then, you can make an HTML button that you can embed in your page. When a user clicks the button, it processes the selling of a specific item from that spreadsheet. Google handles everything else automatically - it subtracts one from the quantity field in the spreadsheet, processes the payment and sends you an email with the purchase and shipping details. Little to no programming required.

Of course, this can't work with PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

First off, paypal comes in many different flavors.  From the simple they host the order form and process payments way on up to all you do is pass them the credit card info and charge amount and they process it.

With that in mind I don't believe they support selling a limited quantity of items.  This is something you would have to provide with your site.

Which leaves us with: are you asking a "how do I code this" type of question or something more general.  If the former then please provide language and what you have so far.  If the latter, then you might try at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Now regarding eventwax charging for usage, that is a perfectly legit thing to do.  They are providing a service which allows people to sell a limited number of things, ensure that those things aren't over sold (which can be difficult depending on your db transactional experience), and handle payment processing.

All said and done there are really several companies which will get a piece of the action so to speak.  Paypal is one, the credit card companies are another.  If you are using paypal's payflow pro gateway then there is at least two other companies involved: your bank and the transaction processor themselves.

Which leads us to why people pay companies like event wax.  Quite frankly, it's easy they don't have to screw around with programming something, and it works right now.  There's a lot that can be said about doing things this way.  Usually you just include all of this into the cost of doing business.